# Link to Mathematica Help in a text cell

Tags: notebooks, documentation, hyperlink

In a text cell e.g.

The Mathematica built-in command to use is Solve.....

I'd like to insert a link on the word Solve, not to the external URL of Wolfram Documentation Center, but to internal Mathematica help page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

First, evaluate the following:

```
Hyperlink["Solve", "paclet:ref/Solve"]
```

Then copy the output link and paste it into your text cell.

Comment: With Solve it works, thanks. I tried the same with FullSimplify and I obtain an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of error? Have you misspelled it? ``Hyperlink["FullSimplify", "paclet:ref/FullSimplify"]``

Comment: Yes I misspelled it. Thanks again

Comment: @CharlesG I've usually it done via the menu hyperlink dialog: type formatted text, select text, menu Insert > Hyperlink..., then type paclet:ref/Solve or http... etc.  You can link to other cells, too (using `CellTags`).

Comment: Very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with buttons.

```
Row[Table[
  Hyperlink[Button[i], "paclet:ref/" <> i], 
  {i, {"Solve", "FullSimplify"}}]]
```

[image]

You can add more items as required. I hope it helps.

Comment: Very useful, thanks.